# Sticky post of current viewing author?

Tags: author, sticky-post

How to show sticky post of current browsing author on author.php template?

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); 
rsort( $sticky ); 
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 5000 );
query_posts( array(
'post__in' => $sticky,
'author' => $current_user->ID,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'caller_get_posts'=> 5 
) );
```

This works fine, but it shows sticky posts of all authors not just of current viewing author.

Comment: You should **never** use `query_posts`. It breaks the simple functionalities that you actually needed to make everything work. Also, note that `caller_get_posts` has been depreciated years ago. It should be `ignore_sticky_posts`. You should really turn debug on while developing as this is one notice that would have slapped your eyes first :-). Just one other thing, `caller_get_posts` should be either `0` or `1`. `5` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

I find what was missing ($wp_query->queried_object_id;), here is answer:

```
$current_browsing_author = $wp_query->queried_object_id; // Get current browsing author
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); 
rsort( $sticky ); 
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 5000 );
query_posts( array(
'post__in' => $sticky,
'author' => $author,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'caller_get_posts'=> 5
) );
```